# How to Stabilize iwlwifi in 15.04 of Asus Zenbook ux305?

Tags: 15.04, laptop, asus, iwlwifi

Can anyone tell me how to stabilize the `iwlwifi` from Intel Corp. Wireless 7265 on the new Asus UX305 Zenbook with Ubuntu 15.04? The speed goes up and down like hell - but doesn't cut off though. For two days, I've read and applied all (but few) 'possible' answers, but to no avail.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX305
Ubuntu: 15.04

Comment: Intel releases thoroughly validated combos of driver / firmware combinations: Take a look at: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wifi losing connection, weak signal, Intel 7260 adapter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter)

Comment: Have you thought about accepting any answers? Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo` and add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` using your preferred text editor:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=0
```

Then reboot your computer to effect the change.